# Is it bad to use vars()

Tags: python, variables

I have a string expression that I need to do eval on. This expression may have key names from a given dictionary and values for those keys may or may not be strings. For my eval to be able to evaluate those names, I am creating variables with the key names that appear in that dict and assign it the value from the dict as in the example below. But from what I have read [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars), vars() should nto be used. This has made me worry about the stability as well as risks of what I have implemented. Any thoughts or suggestions to how to implmenet this in a better way?

```
def test(e1,d1):
 for k,v in d1.iteritems():
     if k in e1:
        vars()[k]=v
 return eval(e1)

test('x+y', {'x':1, 'y':2})
```

Thanks!!

Comment: bigger problem: it's a bad idea to use `eval()`.  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way to do what you're trying to do: the optional `globals` and `locals` arguments to `eval`.

```
def test(e1, d1):
    return eval(e1, globals(), d1)
```

does the same thing as your code but without needing to muck with `vars`.  If you can get away with passing an empty dictionary as the second argument instead of `globals()`, that will insulate you from side effects of `e1`.

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, @MRAB and @murgatroid99 eval(e1,d1) does work. But in order to be able to use some functions from the module, I had to use eval(e1, globals(),d1) as suggested by @Zack. But again, isn't passing the globals a risky thing to do??

Comment: Evaluating untrusted strings is *the* risky thing to do. Not passing the globals doesn't make it less risky.

Comment: And also you can allow just the functions you want with same method. Better than using all globals.

Comment: I sort of agree with you@Rosh Oxymoron. Thanks @utdemir. That might be a better thing to do. But for now, globals() works for me. Thanks again all!!

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this:

```
>>> eval('x+y', {'x':1, 'y':2})
3
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval), it looks like you can get the same effect by doing

```
def test(e1, d1):
  return eval(e1, locals=d1)
```